# How to create a custom keyboard overlay menu for OSX?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Does OSX have an API to create custom keyboard overlay menus that follow the user's input, like their Emoji menu?

[image]

If not, what would be the way around it? Creating an NSWindow that uses the Accessibility API and follows the user input?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should use [NSPopover](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSPopover_Class/) for this purpose. To find out current caret position to point the popover to, use `NSTextView`'s `selectedRanges`-property.